# How do I tell ReadTheDocs to build my project packages from a sub-directory?

Tags: setup.py, read-the-docs

I have a repository that contains three python packages: a main package, and two addon packages, with shared documentation. Each project is in its own directory, with its own setup.py, as so:

- Repository

  - Main Project

    - setup.py
  - Addon One

    - setup.py
  - Addon Two

    - setup.py
  - Documentation

    - RST files, RTD conf, etc.

Previously, I was using setuptools.find_packages() to build my packages, but was having issues with the contents of the packages bleeding together, as they shared namespaces. So I switched to specifying the packages I wanted to build, such as

`packages=["Main Package"]`

However, this broke my ReadTheDocs auto-build, where I had specified

```
- method: setuptools
  path: Main Project
```

in .readthedocs.yml, with RTD now complaining my package (inside the Main Project directory) doesn't exist, as it attempts to build it.

In my project, I use a script to build the packages, where I move into each directory, run its setup, then move out. Works fine, my packages and documentation all build locally. However, it looks like RTD is only using the defined `path` to prepend my setup.py script, and therefore not finding the source package as the working directory is the parent directory (but I could be wrong!).

I've read through the documentation, including https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/4354 where the feature was originally added, but I have not been able to find a solution myself yet.

**How can I tell RTD to change directory before building the packages, or is there an alternative approach that will support my repo structure?**

Repository in question is [here](https://github.com/nc-bradley/Hokohoko).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I changed my local build script to use the root project directory, as per-RTD. I then added the directive   `package_dir={"": "[directory]"}` to the `setuptools.setup()` calls in each project's `setup.py`.